# Can be cgi execution be conditioned to ServerName?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, virtual-host, debian-stretch, cgi

I configured several VirtualHost entries.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain1.domain.tld
        [...]
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain1
        [...]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain2.domain.tld
        [...]
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain2
        [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Later I enabled cgi (cgid) for some reason. Since then that CGI *is triggered* by asking in some path `domain.tld/a_path_for_a_cgi/`. As far I can see, not depending on subdomains configured for VirtualHost entries.

I would want that to be disabled for most of the subdomains:

```
subdomain1.domain.tld/a_path_for_a_cgi/ => disallow or not to find
subdomain2.domain.tld/a_path_for_a_cgi/ => disallow or not to find
subdomain3.domain.tld/a_path_for_a_cgi/ => allow
```

Is this possible in Apache server, or should I fork the scenario in order to have two Apache servers? Should I fork the scenario anyway for security since cgi shipped disabled (Debian Stretch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable CGI only in a specific `VirtualHost`, then move your cgi-specific directives (`ScriptAlias` or the `<Directory/>`-block containing `Options +ExecCGI`, whichever is configured) from the main server config to the target `VirtualHost`.

Module `mod_cgi` (or `mod_cgid`) is of course active in all vhosts if it is enabled in the server, but you don't have to use it in every vhost.

It is true that most modules are disabled by default for security and performance reasons, but IMO you don't need to setup a second server only because you need this module in one vhost. It should be sufficient if you can't execute any scripts in the other vhosts (missing `ScriptAlias`/`ExecCGI` or forbidden access to the script `<Directory/>`).

Links:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgid.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgi.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias

Comment: It wasn't easy, but I made it, and I wouldna made it without this.